# How to import a module from a module within a package?

Tags: python, import, module, package

I've heard that Python imports can be weird and I feel really stupid for not being able to fix this myself; so please somebody kindly explain how this import situation can possibly be a problem.

Directory structure:

```
├── main.py
└── sub
    ├── sub1.py
    └── sub2.py
```

Say sub1 defines function1:

```
# sub1.py
def function1():
    return "function 1 result"
```

sub2 imports sub1 and uses function1 in function2:

```
# sub2.py
import sub1

def function2():
    return f"function 2 result: {sub1.function1()}"
```

Calling function2 from main.py:

```
from sub.sub2 import function2

print(function2()
```

This throws an exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub1'`.

Why? Shouldn't main.py see sub and sub.sub1 and sub.sub2; and shouldn't sub1 and sub2 see each other?

Comment: try using import sub.sub1 in sub2.py

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. As a matter of fact this works; import sub.sub1 makes sub.sub1.function1 available in sub2! First of all: thanks! Secondly: Why exactly is that? If I call sub2 with just import sub1 it works, but not from main.py.

Comment: it needs to be in the same level as that of sub1 & sub2 to view it

Answer (score 1):

Change `sub2.py` to this

```
# sub2.py
import sub.sub1

def function2():
    return f"function 2 result: {sub.sub1.function1()}"
```

The imports are relative to the `main.py`. Therefore, the subdirectory `sub` is required to be part of the import statement even for imports of modules on the same level.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But now sub2 can't run on its own anymore without throwing an exception... I find this extremely awkward.

Comment: That is true. I would recommend reading this. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time